# Adding object to a list by value (which is not just a reference)

Tags: asp.net, .net, list

```
public List<RoleAssignment> lstRoleAssignments1 = new List<RoleAssignment>();
public List<RoleAssignment> lstRoleAssignments2 = new List<RoleAssignment>();


public class RoleAssignment
{
int RoleAssignmentId{get;set;}
}

RoleAssignment objRoleAssign = new RoleAssignment();
objRoleAssign.RoleAssignmentId = 1;

lstRoleAssignments1.Add(objROleAssign);

objRoleAssign.RoleAssignmentId = 2;
lstRoleAssignments2.Add(objROleAssign);
```

Both of these lists have one object and value for the property RoleAssignmentId is **2** in both the cases.

What I want is that RoleAssignmentId in lstRoleAssignments1 is 1 and in lstRoleAssignments2 is 2. I cannot use structs as I need to use list as a property and hence will need to instantiate it within the class. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new instance of RoleAssignment

```
RoleAssignment objRoleAssign = new RoleAssignment();
objRoleAssign.RoleAssignmentId = 1;    
lstRoleAssignments1.Add(objROleAssign);

objRoleAssign = new RoleAssignment();
objRoleAssign.RoleAssignmentId = 2;
lstRoleAssignments2.Add(objROleAssign);
```

or

```
lstRoleAssignments1.Add(new RoleAssignment { RoleAssignmentId = 1 });
lstRoleAssignments2.Add(new RoleAssignment { RoleAssignmentId = 2 });
```

Comment: Was just typing the same answer when this came through!

Comment: Yes we can do that but adding of object to the list goes inside a for loop which goes for say 20000 times and I don't want to create these many objects.

Comment: @devdigital `RoleAssignment objRoleAssign = new RoleAssignment(); for(int i=0; i<20000; i++){ objRoleAssign.RoleAssignmentId = i; lstRoleAssignments1.Add(objROleAssign); objRoleAssign.RoleAssignmentId = i+1; lstRoleAssignments2.Add(objROleAssign); }`